# What does $\int \sin(dx)$ mean?

Tags: integration

**This is only about, how I came up with this weird idea.**

> I was considering about relationship between radius($r$),arc of the circle ($s$) and radian ($\theta$) such that;
>
> [image]
>
> $$\boxed{r/s=\theta}$$
>
> And to convince myself completely, I wanted to try following method.
>   When $s,\phi$ are very small like $\delta s$ and $\delta \phi$, we can assume that the triangle that $rsr$ with angle $\delta \phi$ that is;
>   [image]
>
> So from the triangle, we can conclude that $$\sin\left(\frac{\delta \phi}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\delta s}{2r}$$ and while $\delta s,\delta \phi$ go to the $0$ we can take integral at both side.

**Conclusion:**

What does following mean?

$$\boxed{I=\displaystyle\int \sin(dx)}$$

**1.**

I considered that what if we take the integral to inside of $\sin(x)$?

so $I=\sin (x+C)$

**2.**

I've tried definition of riemann integral.

$$\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)dx=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n f\left(a+k\dfrac{b-a}{n}\right)\left(\dfrac{b-a}{n}\right)$$

But what is the function? $f(dx)$ doesn't look like just $f(x)$ or I can try following but it doesn't make any sense to me, as well.

$$\displaystyle\int f(dx)=\int \dfrac{f(dx)}{dx}dx$$ so $U(x)=\dfrac{f(dx)}{dx}$, but I couldn't finish.

Comment: In terms of Riemann sums, I imagine you'd have: $$\int_a^bf(dx)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^nf\left(\frac{b-a}n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)f\left(\frac{b-a}n\right)$$Though this is just a guess.

Comment: That's mostly meaningless

Comment: just an idea: probably (not sure) $\mathrm dx$ is defined in non-standard analysis in terms of infinitesimals. If this is the case then we can find a meaning for some expression of the kind $f(\mathrm dx)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Many ideas have been meaningless in the beginning, but later got a rigorous mathematical treatment, e.g. the Dirac $\delta$ "function". The idea in the question is not that stupid and actually can be given a meaning.

Comment: The most natural value of $f(dx)$ is $f'(0) \, dx$. Generally, $f(x+dx) = f(x) + f'(x) \, dx$. Therefore, $U(x) = f'(0)$.

Comment: @md2perpe Well, if this is the idea you had in mind when you lectured Hagen, I think I will stay with his healthy skepticism...

Comment: Oops, I made an error. It should of course be $f(dx) = f(0) + f'(0) \, dx$.

Comment: @Did. Do you have a better interpretation?

Comment: @md2perpe Do we **have to** have an interpretation at all?

Comment: @Did, of course not. But when there actually is an interpretation, why deny it?

Comment: @md2perpe Because it has neither meaning nor use, perhaps?

Comment: @Did. If it has no use, why do people use it?

Comment: @md2perpe Who does? Who did? Ever?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62314/discussion-between-md2perpe-and-did).

Comment: @md2perpe "Physicists, including me. Probably even mathematicians." Some physicists have strange customs thus everything is possible in this regard. But mathematicians? My guess is that you are simply making this up.

Comment: If physicists use something, it *is* obviously useful even if it's not rigorous. In that case, isn't it better for mathematicians to take seriously and to look for a rigorous treatment than to just be upset?

Comment: https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1643154125718751&substory_index=0&id=601278736572967

Comment: You can give $\sin dx$ a formal meaning with $dx^2=0$, an axiom we impose on infinitesimals when we write $f(x+dx)-f(x)=f^\prime(x)dx$ (just think about Taylor series), so $\sin dx=dx-\frac16dx^3+\cdots=dx$. Then $\sin dx=\int dx=x+C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help: for very small angles $\sin(x) = x$ is a very good approximation.  You can use this to show: $\dfrac{\delta \phi}{2} =\dfrac{\delta s}{2r}$ which leads to $\delta \phi = \dfrac{\delta s}{r}$ and now you can integrate both sides to show $s=2\pi r$.

Note: I respectfully point out that arc-length is proportional to both radius and angle so: $ s = r \phi$;  I think you might have a typo in your first boxed equation.

But I don't think I answered the question... what could $\int \sin(dx)$ mean.

One possible way to look at what $\sin(dx)$ means could come from the definition of the derivative:
$f'(x)=\lim_{dx \to 0} \left[ \frac {f(x+dx)-f(x)} {dx} \right]$

now take some liberty with the limit and move it to the whole equation level.  Also, evaluate the equation at zero.

$\lim_{dx \to 0} \left[ f'(0)= \frac {f(0+dx)-f(0)} {dx} \right]$

And rearrange to isolate $f(dx)$.

$\lim_{dx \to 0} \left[ f(dx)=f(0)+f'(0) dx \right]$

So: $\lim_{dx \to 0} \left[ \sin(dx) = \sin(0)+\cos(0)dx = dx \right]$

Which gets us back to the approximation that $\sin(x) = x$ for very small angles.

Answer (score 0):

With particular reference to the sector of circle given
$$ \boxed{r = s \cdot \theta} $$
is incorrect, chasing it could lead to weird results.
$$ \boxed{s = r\cdot \theta} $$
is correct, leading to correct result.

Answer (score 0):

The text that you reproduced does not mention the "conclusion"

$$\int\sin(dx)$$ which is meaningless (there isn't even a variable $x$ in the explanation).

What you can write is

$$\sin\left(\frac{\delta \phi}{2}\right)\approx\frac{\delta \phi}{2}=\dfrac{\delta s}{2r}$$

and from this, replacing small increments by differentials,

$$S=\oint ds=\int_0^\theta r\,d\phi=r\theta.$$